# Redirect Plugins.php to New Plugin Page

Tags: plugins, multisite, wp-admin

I have a multisite install and need to redirect the default plugin page to another admin page that will handle plugins. For example, if they request `/wp-admin/plugins.php`, then it should redirect them to `/wp-admin/admin.php?page=pretty-plugins.php` if they are not a network admin. The code below is what I have come up with so far, but I need help finishing it. Any help and suggestions would be appreciated.

```
function block_direct_plugin_page_access() {
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'update_core') && ) //And requests plugins.php
    {
        //Redirect to new plugin page because they are not a network admin.
        wp_safe_redirect( '[Insert Link Here]', 301 ); 
        exit;
    }
}

add_action("muplugins_loaded", "block_direct_plugin_page_access");
```

Comment: Just out of interest: Why do you want a different plugins page? What is the problem you are trying to solve? [Hint: Take a look at this plugin](https://github.com/franz-josef-kaiser/current-admin-info).

Comment: **@kaiser** I have WPMUDEV's pretty plugin page plugin activated. It looks better than the default WordPress plugin page. https://premium.wpmudev.org/project/pretty-plugins/

Comment: The plugins install page will get a major overhaul with the upcoming version. Just saying.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that. It looks so much nicer when updating. But my non-technical users like the pretty plugins plugin better...

Comment: Take a look at the plugin I linked in the first comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little bit of trial and error, I finally got my code to work. This will redirect `http://example.com/wp-admin/plugins` to `http://example.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=pretty-plugins.php` if the current user doesn't have access to update core.

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'block_direct_plugin_page_access' );  
function block_direct_plugin_page_access() {
    global $pagenow;
    if ( ! current_user_can('update_core') && 'plugins.php' === $pagenow ) {
        if ( function_exists('admin_url') ) {
            wp_redirect( admin_url('admin.php?page=pretty-plugins.php') );
        } else {
            wp_redirect( get_option('siteurl') . '/wp-admin/' . 'admin.php?page=pretty-plugins.php' );
        }
    }
}
```